# Cannot restart container, how to restart Docker container?

Tags: docker, influxdb

When I print list

```
docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
f15a180315d3        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   2 hours ago         Exited (128) 2 hours ago                       influxdb
7b753ba600df        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   3 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                         nervous_fermi
2ddc5d9af400        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                         nostalgic_varahamihira
2e174a82d38d        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours a                           modest_mestorf
```

But if I try restart

```
docker container restart influxdb
```

I get

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container influxdb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint influxdb (06ee4d738dffecd1a202840699a899286f4bbb88392e4eb227d65670108687a6): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8086: bind: address already in use

netstat -nl -p tcp  | grep 8086
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      1985/influxd
```

How to restart docker container?
If I go for

```
docker kill influxdb
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: influxdb: Container f15a180315d38c2f5fac929b2d0b9be3e8ca2a09033648b5c5174c15a64c4d71 is not running
```

Comment: what if you kill it, then start it again?

Comment: @tatmanblue Should I use rmi?

Comment: I was just thinking of using these commands: 1) docker kill .... 2) docker start.

Comment: @tatmanblue No,it says container is not running.

Comment: Maybe some other process is using this port?

Comment: @Nebril How to check this?

Comment: Are you able to kill the `influxd` at pid `1985`? E.g. with `kill 1985` (`kill -9 1985`, if first one does not terminate the process)

Comment: @Murmel I am ,I have killed it now with sudo kill 1985.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

As indicated by the error message:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container influxdb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint influxdb (06ee4d738dffecd1a202840699a899286f4bbb88392e4eb227d65670108687a6): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8086: bind: address already in use

The port 8086 was already blocked ( therefore the `address already in use` part) by another process. Therefore the container was not able to run, because the container tried to start `influxdb`, but failed because of the already bound port.
Additionally the output of `netstat` provided the hint, which process occupies the port:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp  | grep 8086
tcp6       0      0 :::8086    :::*    LISTEN      1985/influxd
```

(see the last part: `1985/influxd`)

**Solution**

Kill the other process (first check, if the process is busy and you should save data before stopping it), e.g. using the `kill` command:

```
kill 1985
```